# Getting the TypeError - 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Code:

```
arr = []
for i in range(1,100,2):
    arr.append(i)
print(sum(arr))
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Can you share the exact error traceback? I am not able to reproduce it! Is this the entire code, or the actual problem is some other part of the code?

Comment: I will take a wild guess that you have `sum = ...` somewhere in your code...

Comment: A side note, this loop is really unnecessary. You can just do `sum(range(...))`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have used the variable - `sum` (int datatype) earlier which is different from the inbuilt function `sum()` you are trying to call.

Hence, it is usually not advisable to use pre-defined in-built function names for variables.